# Combine / merge contents of columns in Google Sheet into a single column based on a condition

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with multiple columns. Each column represents a recipe. Each column has a week number (e.g. 2, 3, 4)... Below the week number, we have a variable number of ingredients. I want to be able to merge all the ingredients from a given week into a single column.

### Sample Data

[image: Sample Data]

I know how to *statically* merge ranges e.g. `{B4:B20;C4:C20}` and I can also think of using an if statement to check the week value e.g. `=if(B1=2,{B4:B20;C4:C20})` but that's not close to what I want. I need to check the range `B1:Z1` for the value of the week and if that value is X (let's say 2) then take the ingredients in `B2:B` and tack them on to `C2:C` and so on...

Comment: can you show screenshot of desired result based on your sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this should do it:

`=QUERY(FLATTEN(FILTER(B3:Z,B1:Z1=2)),"WHERE Col1 Is Not Null")`

`FILTER` keeps (i.e., "filters in") only the data in B3:Z where the header is `2`.

`FLATTEN` forms one column (blank cells and all) from the `FILTER` results.

`QUERY` keeps only non-blank (i.e., `Is Not Null`) entries from that single-column list.